# How can I limit views results based on the value of two fields?

Tags: views, 8

I may have to do this programmatically, but I was wondering if there's another way in the UI. Basically, I have a list of articles with Volume and Issue fields. I want the view to only show articles that are in the latest Issue of the latest Volume. I've been trying with aggregation settings and sorting, I can get the articles grouped, but I can't limit to *just* the latest. To complicate things, I'd also like to group the results by a Type field.

Comment: What is the field type of `latest Issue` & `latest Volume` ?

Comment: @NoSssweat both are lists with static key pair values.